# jq injects literal newline and escape characters instead of an actual newline

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "overview_ui": {
    "display_name": "my display name",
    "long_description": "my long description",
    "description": "my description"
  }
}
```

I grab it like so:

```sh
overview_ui=$(jq -r ".overview_ui" service.json)
```

I then want to use it to replace content in another JSON file:

```sh
jq -r --arg updated_overview_ui_strings "${overview_ui}" '.overview_ui.${language} |= $updated_overview_ui_strings' someOtherFile.json
```

This works, however it also introduces visible newline `\n` and escape `\` characters instead of actually preserving the newlines as newlines. Why does it do that?

```
"en": "{\n  \"display_name\": \"my display name\",\n  \"long_description\": \"my long description\",\n  \"description\": \"my description\"\n}",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have read the `overview_ui` variable in as a string (using `--arg`) so when you assigned it, you assigned that string (along with the formatting). You would either have to parse it as an object (using `fromjson`) or just use `--argjson` instead.

```
jq -r --argjson updated_overview_ui_strings "${overview_ui}" ...
```

Though, you don't really need to have to do this in multiple separate invocations, you can read the file in as an argument so you can do it in one call.

```
$ jq --argfile service service.json --arg language en '
.overview_ui[$language] = $service.overview_ui
' someOtherFile.json
```

Comment: I preferred using `argjson`. Thank you!